# Twilio Is it possible to extend the time to enter the access code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

am using twilio for conference call, when user enter the access code the call will get connected. But the user take some time to enter the access, the call will  get ended automatically. So is it there any possible to extend the time to enter the access code?

This is how am getting the access code to connect call.

```
def voice
twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Say "Please enter access code"
  r.Gather action: "connect" do |g|

  end
end
render xml: twiml.to_xml
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add waiting duration until the key pressed.  Please refer the following link for about gather in twilio. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-timeout

```
def voice
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
   r.Say "Please enter access code"
   r.Gather timeout: '30', action: "connect" do |g|
   end
  end
 render xml: twiml.to_xml
end
```